# Files synchronization tool

Tags: file-synchronization, sftp

I have a Windows workstation and a Linux server. So far I used an SFTP client (WinSCP) to connect with the server for updating/downloading files, but I would like software to immediately upload/download changed files. Basically I would like to have the feeling of maintaining only one directory (mirroring in both directions).

Is there software that can do that?

Answer (score 1):

[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) can do that too:

- **Local to remote**: [Keep remote directory up to date](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date):

  This is a built-in functionality and works instantaneously.

  > *Keep remote directory up to date* is a unique feature of WinSCP. With it you may let WinSCP watch for changes in a local directory and have it automatically reflect the changes on the selected remote directory.
  >
  > Using it, you can, with some limitations, work with local files using your favorite tools and the effect would be as if you were working with remote files directly. In other words, the feature partially replaces commercial remote directory drive mapping tools.

  [image]
- **Remote to local**: [Keep local directory up to date](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_keep_local_directory_up_to_date):

  This is implemented as an extension script. And it cannot work instantaneously, as explained in the extension description:

  > WinSCP supports natively [keeping a remote directory up to date](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date) function thanks to a possibility to get notified by Windows (as a local operating system) about changes in a local directory. None of the supported [file transfer protocols](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/protocols) unfortunately offer a functionality to watch for changes in a remote directory. So the only solution is to run [full remote to local synchronization](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_synchronize_full) in regular intervals.

  [image]

Comment: When I choose 'Keep Local Directory up to Date' and click 'ok' with default settings I get error in PowerShell "Error: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Bin\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded". I checked folder and there is WinSCPnet.dll Maybe this is problem with .NET version? I currently using 4.8

Comment: What version of PowerShell do you have? + What does `[environment]::Version` return in your PowerShell?

Comment: Major Minor Build Revision<br/>2 0 50727 8806

Comment: You didn't answer what version of PowerShell do you have? In any case, your PowerShell loads .NET 2.0, no matter what's the latest .NET version you have installed.

Comment: Ok, everything is working. I needed to upgrade from PowerShell 2.0 to 4.0. Thanks for recommendation.

Comment: I've documented the problem in [Could not load file or assembly ‘file:///…\WinSCPnet.dll’ or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_net_runtime_newer_than_currently_loaded).